# Calls to RPC sometimes gets Error: Connection refused or URL couldn't be resolved

Tags: go-ethereum, clique, server-side

I have a backend server that constantly gets logs and parses data from my client node (Clique non-sealer). I restrict the number of calls from my backend server -> client node to 25 at a time.

1. Is this count too high?
2. Is there a limit as to how many simultaneous connections the node can have?

FYI, I also have Cloudflare routing to resolve the domain name that goes to the AWS EC2 instance where its hitting the client node. The EC2 instance is also behind an Nginx server as well. I am thinking that the Nginx might be rate limiting or throttling the requests?

Anyone have similar experience with this sort of setup?